# aligning component in a line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Ticket" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient" type="button">
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                     </button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Tools
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> New Ticket
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a problem with "Search Tools" button, it went down in a new line.
It looks like:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form-group` and `form-inline` should do the trick here.: [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/RH7lIV8jBq)

```
<form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Ticket" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                       <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient" type="button">
                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                       </button>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Tools
            </button>
</form>
```

integrating my form in your current system:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group col-md-7">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Ticket">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                       <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient" type="button">
                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                       </button>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient col-md-5">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Tools
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> New Ticket
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work, it puts every component in the new line... http://i.imgur.com/2Yr8dmE.png

Comment: had some little issue. fixed it. added working bootply @Kapparino

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Ticket" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                       <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient" type="button">
                           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                       </button>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search Tools
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-default-gradient pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> New Ticket
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that I increased col-md-3 to col-md-6 as it did not fit the form + button. Hope this helps

Comment: hey your solution looks good but you are using div instead of a form. apart from that i think it looks great actually.

Comment: I used div because @Kapparino does not have form tag in his source code. That's why I did not add it.

Comment: yuyokk your solution works fine too, i give you a thumb up, but I like this solution with form-inline and group @CodingEnthusiast gave, with out using the col-md-size

Comment: yes that makes sense. I thought that you need those col-md-X cols.

Comment: one note if you need to make offset, do not use empty tags like <div class="col-md-6"></div>, just use col-md-offset-6.